# For Each Shape in a specific slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub FindingIfShapeNamesCA1Exists()
Dim shp As Shape
  For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(2)

    If shp.Name = "CA1" Then
    MsgBox "y"
    End If

  Next shp
End Sub
```

I am trying to identify if a shape named CA1 is present in a particular slide using the slide indexing.
However I am getting a run-time error: Object doesn't support this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enumerating the slides in the presentation, but not the shapes.
You should enumerates the Shapes in the slide:

```
Sub FindingIfShapeNamesCA1Exists()
    Dim shp As Shape      

    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes
        If shp.Name = "CA1" Then
            MsgBox "y"
        End If
    Next shp        
End Sub
```